# Best javascript library for developing drag and drop web applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, extjs

So far I've been using jquery ui's draggables and droppables, but I've also heard of extjs and I'm sure there are more. I'm looking to develop a (hopefully) professional plugin. What would be the best library to use and or is anyone aware of any limitations to jquery ui's functions for this?

I'm going to need to go 1-3 layers deep at least of dropping things inside each other, if not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options available to you even including the possibility of writing your own drag and drop functionality if you really wanted.

jQuery UI isn't a bad choice and there will be plenty of support going down that route. jQuery UI sortables sounds to fit the behaviour you desire. I've used this for nested drag and drop in the past.

[dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) is a nice vanilla js alternative for drag and drop behaviour supporting IE7+ that could also be a good choice.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the browsers you need to support. HTML5 has native drag & drop support, so if you only have to support IE9 and above, you can just use the attribute draggable=true and handle the drag events; see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp for examples. If you need to support IE8, however, jquery ui is the best (read: easiest) I've used.